# Best practice to give access to std::array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a relatively complex project with many classes, I'll try to simplify it with a simplistic example.

```
class item
{
// a class that holds useful members and methods
}

class user
{
public:
   user(item* i)
   {
      item_to_use = i;
   }

   void do_work()
   {
      //do some work using item_to_use
   }
private:
   item item_to_use;
};

class storage_class
{
public:
   std::array<item, 10> items;
};

class usage_class
{
public:
   usage_class(storage_class &s)
   {
      user0 = user(&s.items.at(0));
      user1 = user(&s.items.at(1));
      user2 = user(&s.items.at(2));
      //etc...
   }
private:
   user user0;
   user user1;
   user user2;
};
```

Please pardon the meaningless example; the main idea i'm trying to point out is that I want to give to `user` objects access to an `item` from `std::array items`.

In that example, I'm doing it with pointers, which is not safe in case `items` is destroyed, so I would rather do that with shared pointers, especially that i'm going to share `item` objects to many other classes (not only 1 as in the example).

So my questions are

- Am I right to assume that it's not safe to simply share the pointer to std::array individual elements? or am i being paranoiac ?
- Would it make any sense to create shared pointer to individual elements of the std::array?
- Or should I create an `std::array<shared_ptr<item>,10>` in the first place?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Using C++17 is an option, by the way

Comment: If you cannot ensure that the array will outlive its 'borrowers', and you want the elements to be available even after the array's destruction, then `std::array<shared_ptr<item>, 10>` would be the way to do it, I think. Definitely do not create `shared_ptr`s to existing elements, because `shared_ptr` *owns* its element, as well as `std::array`, and this would lead to double-free (undefined behaviour)

Comment: It sounds like you haven't completely worked out the ownership scheme of your project. What actually owns the items and the users? What is the expected lifetimes of those objects? You need to have this figured out before you can decide what the best strategy is.

Comment: you're right @FrançoisAndrieux, i'm still in early design stage, and this is part of the actual brainstorming process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a storage class, I'm assuming it outlives all the users and usage classes and "owns" the items. If that's the case, you're fine to just pass a pointer to the items in the array around and shared_ptr would just add unnecessary overhead.

Will you always be using a std::array? If you end up using a vector down the road, passing a pointer to the items would NOT be safe in all cases. If you pass a pointer to an item and then the vector gets resized, the pointer you passed in previously is now invalidated. This won't happen to a std::array, but it's something to think about if your design might evolve in that direction. If that might happen, you could use a vector<unique_ptr<item>>, and then pass the underlying pointer from unique_ptr into the methods that take an item*.

Finally, don't use shared_ptr without ruling out other options first. There are relatively few cases where shared_ptr is necessary, and this is probably not one of them. You only need shared_ptr if you can't reason about who the owner of an object is to properly control its lifetime, and in many cases that is a sign of a poor design.

Comment: *"Finally, don't use shared_ptr."* This is a matter of opinion. You are right that `std::shared_ptr` should not be the default solution you immediately jump to, but their use cases are not so rare that they should be considered red flags.

Comment: There are cases where a shared_ptr makes sense, but I don't think a newcomer to C++ like the OP will run into those cases for awhile. Perhaps I could reword that to "Don't use shared_ptr without ruling out other options first". Personally I almost never run into cases where it makes sense at work, but I understand that in other domains it might be more common. 

I'd link the OP to this talk by Herb Sutter for a better discussion on memory management options:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE